# How to wait a in a for loop until ajax call finishes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to developing web sites and I'm developing a small web site. Here I'm using ajax to show new comments. this is the function I wrote

```
function show_comments() {
$('div#P_all_posts>div').each(function () {
    id = this.id.replace("post", "");
    $.ajax({

        url: 'http://localhost/seppro/index.php/group/show_comments',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {

           document.getElementById("cmnt"+id).innerHTML=data;

        },
        error: function (err, req) {
            alert(err)
        },
        async: false
    });

});
setTimeout("show_comments()", 5000);
}
```

The PHP

model

```
public function showcmnts(){ 
    $sql="select * from tbl_cmnt 
          where postid='".$this->input->post("id")."'"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); return $query->result(); 
}
```

controller

```
 public function show_comments(){
    $data['cmntlist'] = $this->Group_model->showcmnts();
    $this->load->view('group/grp_cmnts', $data);
}
```

view

```
foreach ($cmntlist as $cmnt):
echo $cmnt->comment . "<br>";
endforeach;
```

even though I set `async: false`  in the ajax success function I can only get the last id(id of the last div) inside the ajax success function.but when i alert the id(id of the div) above the ajax part i am getting the correct id . so how can I pause the loop until ajax function finishes.sorry for my bad English please help me

Comment: Show the PHP script that you are running on the server with this AJAX call

Comment: `public function showcmnts(){
        
        
        $sql="select * from tbl_cmnt where postid='".$this->input->post("id")."'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
        
    }
`
@RiggsFolly this is the php script

Comment: @RiggsFolly  think nothing is wrong with the php part here. when i simply alert the id  inside the ajax it only showing the last id.but when i alert it above the ajax it is showing the correct one

Comment: That code is a class method and does not pass anything back to the javascript!!! So where is the rest of the code that runs on the server.

Comment: @RiggsFolly okay i have updated all of it plz look at that again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your ajax call to immediately invoked function and pass `id` to it:

```
    $('div#P_all_posts>div').each(function () {
        id = this.id.replace("post", "");
        (function(id) {
            $.ajax({

                url: 'http://localhost/seppro/index.php/group/show_comments',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    document.getElementById("cmnt" + id).innerHTML = data;

                },
                error: function (err, req) {
                    alert(err)
                },
                async: false
            });
        })(id)
    });
```

It seems like your `id` var is global, and on each loop it rewrites its value, and by the time ajax is completed, `id` is equal to last value in loop.

Comment: oh thank you it's get the job done but it executes more time than i want.

Comment: oh even though the idea is good and it is working it slows down the browser soo much that after 5 or 6 second user cant even type somthing.but than you for the help

Comment: @PawaniMadhawaBandaraHerath try to set `async: true`. Ajax will freez browser if it `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in the fact that you never call the function `show_comments()` for first time in the the script

1. I recommend you to use this when you call it

   setInterval(show_comments(), 5000)

And remove the `setTimeOut()` from `show_comments()`

2. Or you can just keep `setTimeOut()` and call `show_comments()` inside the script path or in the function you are going to call it

Comment: i called the show_comments() function on onload.the function is working the only problem is i am only getting the last id when i alert the id inside the ajax part..when i alelrt it above the ajax part i am getting the correct id

Comment: `setInterval()` is also giving the same problem